# Get the ID of a next greater/less Value

Tags: mysql, join

imagine you have follwing table given

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 1 |

Depends on your case you need the ID of the next smaller
or greater value.

So the select of ID=2 would give u either 4 or 1.

How would you solve that?

thanks in advice.
Eing

Comment: can you lease also tag your mysql version, as this can be soverd with window function, which are only available in mysql 8

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the table to itself on the `id` field = the `value` + 1 and again on `value` - 1. My example uses an `INNER JOIN` which will only return the cases where both match, otherwise you'll want to use the appropriate `OUTER JOINS` or two separate queries, to not filter out.

```
SELECT * -- Replace with only the columns you need as SELECT * is bad practice
FROM SomeTable ST1
INNER JOIN SomeTable ST2
    ON ST2.id = ST1.value + 1
INNER JOIN SomeTable ST3
    ON ST2.id = ST1.value - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
       value,
       LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY value) previous_id,
       LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY value) previous_value,
       LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY value) next_id,
       LEAD(value) OVER (ORDER BY value) next_value
FROM source_table;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=380e32647839d5bca98f5ccfe7fdb113)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.

I thougt it was clear but i need two different queries. One which gives me the highest lower id of given value and one which gives me the lowest higher id of given value. The values of value are unique. It is as simple as I thougt. I solved it this way.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `source_table` WHERE `value` > 3 ORDER BY `value` ASC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT `id` FROM `source_table` WHERE `value` < 3 ORDER BY `value` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Then `UNION` those together to get them from a single SQL.